# How are the X and Y axis determined when using the normal transform orientation in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, transforms, coordinates

When using the normal transform orientation in edit mode the Z axis of faces always points in the same direction as the face normal.
In the case of edges the Y axis always points in the same direction as the face.
In the case of vertices the Z axis always points in the smae direction as the vertex normal, that is the split normals of shade smooth without any weighting.

But how are the two other axes determined? For example when transforming a face, how does Blender choose which tangent to use as X and Y axes?

The shader nodes like normal map node use the axes of the UV map to determine the X and Y axes, but in edit mode this isn't the case, as modifying the UV map doesn't influence the X and Y axis of the normal transform orientation in edit mode at all.

Comment: In the case of faces, the X direction is always perpendicular to the longest side.

Comment: Blender source: [transform_orientations.c line 516](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/editors/transform/transform_orientations.c#L516), and later in the same file [line 1291](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/editors/transform/transform_orientations.c#L1291) which leads to [line 304](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/editors/transform/transform_orientations.c#L304), and finally to [line 747](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/editors/transform/transform_orientations.c#L747)